# (Closed) Overlay widgets in R shiny application

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

**tl;dr** I want to overlay a `plotOutput` on top of an `imageOutput`. I have no CSS/HTML knowledge.

The full problem I am facing:
Another **tl;dr** I want to replicate [this](https://github.com/tractor/tractor#usage-from-r) in shiny, and has to be fast!

Imagine a small `3 x 4 x 5` 3D array, made of unit square (so a total of 60 squares). I want the user to visualize the three planes individually. I have three `imageOutput` (or `plotOutput`) for each of the planes, XY, YZ, and XZ. I will refer to these as `plane` hereon. Something like [this](https://s3mn.mnimgs.com/img/shared/content_ck_images/images/Cube.png) (I just did a google search for this, not my image).  When the application is loaded, I render the center of each `plane`, with crosshair pointing (crossing?) at the center of the same. Now when the user clicks on any `plane`, say XY, I get the coordinated of the click in shiny and update the other `plane` with the new images for those, in this case YZ and XZ, with the new `x` and `y` coordinated. Also updating the crosshair for all three. The end result is exactly this the image [here](https://github.com/tractor/tractor#usage-from-r). Except all three are in separate views. 
So I have code that does this already, but the load time is painful. Because the actual input is of dimensions `~ 250 x 250 x 100`. It takes about 2-3sec for all three planes to load. The application is supposed to provide an interface to quickly and easily view the planes, with the least amount of delay. So basically, I am to speed things up.

About the variables used:

1. `x()` is a `reactive` for the input.
2. `meta()` is a `reactive` that stores dimensions of `x()`.
3. `values$xyz` is an array of length 3, for the x, y, and z for crosshair.

I have tried to get as much detail in this post as possible, because it is a complicated question. Please excuse the length of the post.

So far, I have tried a few things:

1. The first idea was to just render the planes on the fly. I had `plotOutput` for the `ui` and the code below for the `server`.

   ```
   output$plotXY <- renderPlot({
       req(x())
       par(oma = rep(0, 4), mar = rep(0, 4), bg = "black")
       graphics::image(1:meta()$X, 1:meta()$Y,
                   x()[, , values$xyz[3]],
                   col = gray(0:64/64),
                   xlab = "", ylab = "",
                   axes = FALSE,
                   useRaster = T)
       abline(h = values$xyz[2], v = values$xyz[1], col = "red")
   })
   ```

   Like I mentioned above, very slow.
2. Thought `ggplot2` would be faster, so basically ported the above code to `ggplot`.

   ```
   ggplot(melt(x()[, , values$xyz[3]]), aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value)) +
     geom_raster(show.legend = F) +
     theme_void() +
     scale_fill_gradient(low = "black", high = "white") +
     geom_vline(xintercept =  values$xyz[1], color = "red") +
     geom_hline(yintercept =  values$xyz[2], color = "red")
   ```

   This did speedup the process some, but it was negligible. I used `microbenchmark`. Also tried [this](http://ikashnitsky.github.io/2017/ggplot2-microbenchmark), but again, nothing promising.
3. Decided to first save all the planes, all XY, YZ, and XZ, as png in a temp files and load when needed. Now using `imageOutput` in `ui`.

   ```
   # preprocessing:
   makePNG <- function(slice) {

     outfile = tempfile(fileext = ".png")
     dims = dim(slice)
     png(outfile, width = dims[1], height = dims[2])
     par(mar = c(0,0,0,0))
     image(slice, useRaster=T, axes=F, col = gray(0:64/64))
     dev.off()

     return(outfile)
   }
   ...
     file_paths_XY <- apply(x(), 3, makePNG) # also in meta()
   ...
   # loading images:
   output$plotXY <- renderImage({
     req(x())
     pos = values$xyz[3]
     file_path = meta()$file_paths_XY[pos]
     list(
       src = file_path
     )
   }, deleteFile = F)
   ```

   This is significantly faster, but naturally, the initial load time is huge! To speed up preprocessing, I tried the `parallel` package, but the overhead of transferring the whole `x()` is too expensive. I am thinking of implementing a lazy loader, so only load maybe 10 per plane, then load 10 more if required. Not come down to implementing yet. But the real problem is, I need the crosshairs (also some rescaling and rotation)! I decided to use `ggplot` again and add a `annotation_custom` layer that would render the image as background, and add crosshair to the plot. Similar to [this](http://thinktostart.com/add-a-background-png-to-ggplot2/). But loading the png again, and redoing everything, slows it down, and honestly seems useless. I used `magick` to load the png faster. But again, too slow. `imager`  too.

I am lost. I have never worked with optimizing, so I do not know `Rcpp`. I am willing to experiment with it, but I want to know if that is the right direction to go, or maybe try something else. I am open to all and any suggestions. Please comment if you need more details or code. Thank you!

Edit: The title lol, I was wondering if it would be possible to somehow overlay a `plotOutput` over the `imageOutput` and get `ggplot` to just add crosshair. I am guessing that would save a lot of time and should be enough to speed it up.

Update: I would love to make this reproducible, but I don't think I have enough experience with R and Shiny for this. It is a shiny app module. And the bigger application calls `callModule` with the path to the image to display. How would I go about to make it reproducible?

Update: I should have probably mentioned that the input array is a greyscale image, but with no limit to the high's or low's (It is not bound to a 0-1 range)

Update: So I coded a mini app on my laptop, the original code is actually very fast. I think the RStudio Server we use at work is rather slow. Nonetheless, I am posting the code.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4, plotOutput("plotXY", click = "plotXY_click")),
    column(4, plotOutput("plotXZ", click = "plotXZ_click")),
    column(4, plotOutput("plotYZ", click = "plotYZ_click"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data <- array(sample(x=100, size=250*250*100, replace = T), dim=c(250,250,100))
  X <- 250
  Y <- 250
  Z <- 100
  dim <- c(250, 250, 100)

  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$xyz <- ceiling(dim/2)

  output$plotXY <- renderPlot({
    par(oma = rep(0, 4), mar = rep(0, 4), bg = "black")

    img_data = data[,,values$xyz[3]]

    graphics::image(1:X, 1:Y,
                    img_data,
                    col = gray(0:64/64),
                    xlab = "", ylab = "",
                    axes = FALSE,
                    useRaster = T)
    abline(h = values$xyz[2], v = values$xyz[1], col = "red")
  })

  observeEvent(input$plotXY_click, {
    values$xyz[1] <- input$plotXY_click$x
    values$xyz[2] <- input$plotXY_click$y
  })

   output$plotXZ <- renderPlot({
    par(oma = rep(0, 4), mar = rep(0, 4), bg = "black")

    img_data = data[,values$xyz[2],]

    graphics::image(1:X, 1:Z,
                    img_data,
                    col = gray(0:64/64),
                    xlab = "", ylab = "",
                    axes = FALSE,
                    useRaster = T)
    abline(h = values$xyz[3], v = values$xyz[1], col = "red")
  })

  observeEvent(input$plotXZ_click, {
    values$xyz[1] <- input$plotXZ_click$x
    values$xyz[3] <- input$plotXZ_click$y
  })

  output$plotYZ <- renderPlot({
    par(oma = rep(0, 4), mar = rep(0, 4), bg = "black")

    img_data = data[values$xyz[1],,]

    graphics::image(1:Y, 1:Z,
                    img_data,
                    col = gray(0:64/64),
                    xlab = "", ylab = "",
                    axes = FALSE,
                    useRaster = T)
    abline(h = values$xyz[3], v = values$xyz[2], col = "red")
  })

  observeEvent(input$plotYZ_click, {
    values$xyz[2] <- input$plotYZ_click$x
    values$xyz[3] <- input$plotYZ_click$y
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Final update: So it turns out that the server we use is generally doing a lot of heavy lifting with simulation and stuff, slowing down the code by a lot. Although the question has not been solved, I guess we were looking at the wrong problem. Regardless, I am going to award the bounty to Simon. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Do you plan on making it reproducible? :')

Comment: I don't know of a good way to do so. Any advice? Will update the thread with details

Answer (score 1):

This approach uses a 3D array, each plane of which is a grey scale image. It can be generalized to rgb by tracking each color separately. Inspired by handling matrices in Matlab.

First setting up some dummy data:

```
# GREY
G = runif(250*250*100)
G = array(G, c(250,250,100))
```

Where G is the grey scale components of the images.

Suppose the coordinate `X = 40` is selected. Then we extract the YZ `plane`:

```
ptm = proc.time()
X = 40
YZ_panel = G[40,,]
```

This can be displayed as an image in ggplot:

```
g <- rasterGrob(YZ_panel, interpolate=TRUE)

qplot(c(1,10,10,1,1),c(1,1,25,25,1),geom="blank") +
  annotation_custom(g, xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=25) +
  geom_line(aes(x=c(5,5), y=c(0,25)), color="red") +
  geom_line(aes(x=c(0,10), y=c(10,10)), color="red") + 
  coord_fixed()
```

Using `proc.time()` I got results of under half a second:

```
proc.time() - ptm
   user  system elapsed 
   0.18    0.03    0.21
```

You will of course have to repeat this process for each `plane`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already tried saving and loading as png (option 2). Although I haven't tried `qplot`. Will try and update. Also, the image is greyscale. There is only one 3D array given as input.

Comment: Update: I tried this, but with no improvement with speeds. Saving and loading the png everytime a click is detected is probably too heavy. I tried using a `imageOutput` and passing the file path as `src`, but again, not fast.

Comment: Also, could you mention where you assigned `ptm` so I can get a better understanding of which part of the code took less than a second? Thanks!

Comment: Answer updated for grey scale, defining `ptm` and removing saving the png (as this is unnecessary). Speed only improved.

Comment: Have you checked the speed/performance of the click observer?

Comment: The click observe is standard shiny click observer. I used the `click` option in `column`. Once I get off work, I will make a mini app with just the required code for reproducibility.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Simon, but the problem was never with the code. :P See thread for more details.